# How to tell if a shape is a Quadrilaterals by only having their lengths?

Tags: algorithm, geometry

Assume that we have only four lengths of a potential Quadrilaterals. Also suppose that they are given in an specific order for simplicity so that any two consequence of length represent two adjacent sides. 
Is there any algorithm by which we can tell that these inputs can make a valid Quadrilaterals?

Comment: Not enough information. Define what you consider an 'invalid' quadrilateral.

Comment: @BasSwinckels -- by valid I meant any four-sided mathematical closed shape (official definition of a quadrilateral)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following:

> Sum of any three sides of a quadrilateral must be greater than the fourth side.

Comment: It seems to be an expansion on valid triangle algorithm. right?

Comment: yup. and the same can be proved mathematically.

Answer (score -1):

Just the triangle formula for quadrilaterals.

Comment: I think you need to provide more details. Among others how this is different from the existing answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/22126293/7733418

Comment: I used my favorite search engine on "triangle formula for quadrilaterals", expecting that I find something which is basically what the existing other answer describes. But I did not find anything (possible becaus of my searchfu being not strong enough....). So while my gut feeling says it is the same I would like you to confirm it is. Note that if it is the same then this is actually a decent answer, which provides the additional insight of the correct name for what the other answer (also helpfully) just technically summarises. You should just say so, one way or another.